# How do I get the value before a certain value from a URL using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

For Example:

```
www.site.com/potato/hello/eweb/TestPage.aspx
// or
www.site.com/potato/eweb/TestPage.aspx
```

I want to get everything before `eweb` from the URL using jQuery no matter how long the url before `eweb` is.

So from the example #1 above, I want to get `www.site.com/potato/hello/` back and `www.site.com/potato/` for example #2 as my result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `split()` the current URL by `eweb` and get the first element of the resulting array:

```
var baseUrl = window.location.href.split('eweb')[0];
```

Comment: No problem, glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `String.prototype.match()` with `RegExp` `/.*(?=eweb)/` to match any characters followed by "eweb"

```js
var str = "www.site.com/potato/hello/eweb/TestPage.aspx";
var res = str.match(/.*(?=eweb)/)[0];
console.log(res)
```